# How to show selective templates in the rule group?

Tags: endeca

Is there any way to show only selective templates corresponding to the rule group ?

For Ex. - I have to rule-groups (MobilePages & WebSearchPages), when I go to create a new landing page templates for mobile are also available in template selection for WebSearchPages And similarly templates created for the use in full-site are available in group for MobilePages.

Is there any way to avoid this, or offer only selective templates for pages corresponding to the rule-group ?

In templates I can only specify the entry of Zone & Page-style but not for rule-group -

```
<ContentTemplate xmlns="http://endeca.com/schema/content-template/2008" type="PageTemplate" id="MobileSubCategoryPage">
      <RuleInfo zone="MobileCategoryPageZone" style="PageStyle"/>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot restrict which types of rules are placed into specific groups.

I have sought such functionality as well. You would think that with group level permissions one would be able to control what goes into the groups as well.

This has likely changed substantially with the move to experience manager that does not have the same group concepts.